# Show conidtional statment on result page based on drop down box from previous page

Tags: php, conditional-statements, echo

I am trying to create a results page, that will only show a statement if the user selected a value of 13 from a dropdown box with the name of technology, after posting from the previous page.  I can't seem to figure out the exact syntax.  However, I have the following:

```
<?php
if $_POST['Technology']="13";
{
echo "Do you have your first month's payment with you?";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if statements should look like

```
if($_POST['Technology']=="13")
{
   echo "Do you have your first month's payment with you?";
}
```

you had a single `=` instead of double `==`, single is used for assigning, double is for comparing, also if conditions are surrounded by `()`, and also do not have a `;`

Answer (score 0):

You must check first if the form data has been posted. Then use the following statement.

```
if(isset($_POST['Technology']) && $_POST['Technology']=='13')
{
   echo "Do you have your first month's payment with you?";
}
```